# Cascading Dropdown Using Ajax and Web Api

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api

This is an ajax call my browser extenions makes to my web api:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $select = $('#brandDropdownList');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:44358/api/brands',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data) {
            $select.html('');
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $select.append('<option id="' + val.brand_id + '">' + val.brand_name + '</option>');
            })
        },
        error: function(){
            $select.html('<option id="-2">Please try again...</option>');
        }
    });
```

This currently calls my API which returns the an JSON array from which I then amend each item to an  tag making a drop down. I then have another drop down which will be dependant on the brand_name the user chooses. How can I do another ajax call to my web API that will populate another drop down based on the brand (specifically the brand_id) so that only products of that chosen brand are shown. I have created the web api controller and it I am currently accessing it via my localhost with the URL 'http://localhost:44358/api/products'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **on change event** on Brand drop-down to get it's product list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $select = $('#brandDropdownList');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:44358/api/brands',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data) {
            $select.html('<option value="">Select brand</option>');
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $select.append('<option value="' + val.brand_id + '">' + val.brand_name + '</option>');
            })
        },
        error: function(){
            $select.html('<option value="-2">Please try again...</option>');
    });
    //When user select any Brand below change event will callled. 
    $('#brandDropdownList').change(function (){
         var brand_id = $(this).val();
         getProducts(brand_id);
    }):

    function getProducts(brand_id){
          $select = $('#productDropdownList')
          $select.html('<option value="">Please wait...</option>');
          $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: 'http://localhost:44358/api/products',
             data:{brand_id : brand_id} //pass brand id to server to filter product of selected brand
             dataType: 'JSON',
             success:function(data) {
                 $select.html('');
                 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $select.append('<option value="' + val.product_id + '">' + val.product_me + '</option>');
                 })
             },
             error: function(){
                 $select.html('<option value="-2">Please try again...</option>');
          });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew I had to use the on change event but wasn't sure how to pass in the brand of as part of the next Ajax call. Greatly appreciated